# Can't place loaded file data into frame which is inside notebook using tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I've create a frame inside notebook as shown in image below. I want to load all the text from a file into that frame inside notebook and also I am unable to read any file except(.txt) and load its data inside notebook frame.

[My UI here in kwic notebook tab a white backgrounds represent frame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6yqD.png)

```
# this is the inside frame of notebook
KWIC_InsideFrame_3 = Frame(KWIC_tab, bg='white', height=460).grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=EW)

# here I'm loading file from directory
def open_file():
    
    selected_items = Lbox.curselection()
    
    # check if any item(s) are selected
    if len(selected_items) == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "No item selected")
        return
    
    # open each selected file and display contents in a frame window
    for item in selected_items:
        filename = Lbox.get(item)
        filename = filename.replace('\\', '/')
        try:
            with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                content = f.read()
# here is the code snippet i got while searching but it is not working.
                frame_fr = Frame(KWIC_InsideFrame_3)
                text = Text(frame_fr)
                text.pack()
                text.insert(END, content)
                
        except:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error opening file " + filename)
```

[I want the out like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVnnQ.png)

Comment: You are never making `frame_fr` visible, therefore the Text it contains cannot be visible.  It wouldn't appear where you expected it to anyway, because its parent `KWIC_InsideFrame_3` is actually None - the result of `.grid()`, rather than the Frame itself.

Comment: I think you are trying to say this:
I've uploaded the piece code, where KWIC_InsideFrame_3 its parent is not none. It is stored inside notebook frame. 
But if my understanding is not right then kindly help me out with it.
Thank you.

Comment: Post a [mre]. Also see [ask]. Do a preliminary debugging. Anyway, the above comment said two things - you didn't pack the ```frame_fr``` and the ```KWIC_InsideFrame_3``` is ```None```. For the latter, just print it by yourself before the ```frame_fr = Frame(KWIC_InsideFrame_3)``` line.